# Available implementations of IEEE 754-2008 (Densely Packed Decimal)

Tags: c++

What are the platform independent options for decimal numbers in c++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly are your portability requirements?  GCC and the IBM compilers have native support in the newest versions.  Intel also has a [library](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-decimal-floating-point-math-library/) for several platforms.

Answer (score 1):

An update: the [mpdecimal](http://www.bytereef.org/mpdecimal/index.html) library is now available on all platforms.